# Postman error while uploading files through form-data body type

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postman, mern

Couldn't upload file
Make sure that Postman can read files inside the working directory.

Comment: What does your Postman request look like? What does your application code look like?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. In your postman man web app go to settings (upper-right "gear icon") > General > Scroll down until you find **working directory and verify the name** (it will be useful later). Sometimes you may find a warning
   icon depending on your operative system. If that is the case make
   sure you opt-in the "Allow reading files from outside working
   directory"
2. On your filesystem go to **C:\Users{YOUR USER}\Postman <<< verify
   that this name is matches the one in settings**. Sometimes by
   default it is set as Postman Agent (if that's the case, postman will
   not be able to read files from your system). Both names should match. (e.g rename Postman and Postman)
3. Make sure your postman Agent is set to "Desktop" on the lower right part of your workspace on the postman web app

Hope it helps. I faced the same issue a couple of minutes ago.

You may also see that new folder are created everytime you upload a file to postman. Inside C:\Users{YOUR USER}\Postman\files

like {gibberish}{the file you've just uploaded} --Don't know why but it doesn't seem to have any negative effects. Perhaps it's just a bug for Windows Users

Comment: Thanks for the help. For me the folder was incorrectly named like in step 2: 'Postman Agent' instead of just 'Postman'. It's shocking that Postman can't fix their stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what works for me in Postman file uploading:

- Use `Put` request as request type
- In request `Body` section, select `binary` type
- Select file

You can also pass query parameters in Put request if needed.